# How to combine two functions in R statistics?

Tags: r

I´m trying to learn R statistics by myself. I've found a very useful [tutorial with nice projects for beginners](https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/index.html), which has been helping me a lot to learn this new language. In one of the projects we create a deck of cards, shuffle it and than deal a hand.

For this, we create two functions:

```
shuffle <- function(cards){
  random <- sample(1:96, size = 96)
  cards[random, ]
}

deal <- function(cards){
  cards[1:10,]
}
```

They work as expected. `deck` is my data-frame:

```
deck2 <- shuffle(deck)
deal(deck2)
         Ability Card.Value Aura
  55     Int          8   -1
  81    Will          4    0
  10     Agi          5    0
  43     Int          4    0
  52     Int          6   -1
  ...
```

I, however, as an exercise, would like to combine this two functions into a sigle function, like this:

```
dealAndSuffle <- function(cards){
  random <- sample(1:96, size = 96)
  cards <- cards[random, ]
  cards[1:10,]  
}
```

However, this new function does not work. Can anyone point me to my mistake, please?

Comment: `sample` provides random result. `set.seed` might be a clue to have same results

Comment: To make what @Clemsang said, the random order would make the results different every time. You'll want to do something like `set.seed(0)` then run your first formulation. Then set the seed back to zero and run the second version.

Comment: Beyond what has been mentioned in the previous comments regarding set.seed... id' just like to check, since you say the function "does not work", is it possible that the typo in the function name is the problem? That is, that you're perhaps defining the function dealAndSuffle (with no 'h'), but calling the function dealAndShuffle (with an 'h')

Answer (score 0):

`sample()` function randomly selects values and therefore even if the same function repeated twice you will get different results. To ensure your combined function gives you the same output, use `set.seed()` function when checking the results:

```
# Create a toy data frame
N <- 96
deck <- data.frame( Ability = sample(c("Int","Will","Agi"), N,  replace=T ), Card.Value=rep(1:24, each=4))


shuffle <- function(cards){
  random <- sample(1:96, size = 96)
  cards[random, ]
}

deal <- function(cards){
  cards[1:10,]
}



dealAndShuffle <- function(cards){
  random <- sample(1:96, size = 96)
  cards <- cards[random, ]
  cards[1:10,]  
}

# Set seed to insure reproducibility
set.seed(12345)
deck2 <- shuffle(deck)
deal(deck2)
#    Ability Card.Value
# 14    Will          4
# 51     Agi         13
# 80     Agi         20
# 90     Int         23
# 92     Int         23
# 24     Agi          6
# 58     Int         15
# 75    Will         19
# 88     Agi         22
# 2      Int          1


# Set seed to insure reproducibility
set.seed(12345)
dealAndShuffle(deck)
#    Ability Card.Value
# 14    Will          4
# 51     Agi         13
# 80     Agi         20
# 90     Int         23
# 92     Int         23
# 24     Agi          6
# 58     Int         15
# 75    Will         19
# 88     Agi         22
# 2      Int          1
```